# Show/Hide specific DIV when selecting an option from a dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to setup a select dropdown from which, using jQuery, each option will display a specific DIV. I have most of the functionality working, I just can't get the displayed DIV to hide once another option is selected. This is my code so far:

```
<select id="contact-location">
    <option value="">-- Select Location --</option>
    <option value="sydneyBranch">Sydney</option>
    <option value="melbourneBranch">Melbourne</option>
</select>

<div id="sydneyBranch" style="display:none">
    CONTENT
</div>

<div id="melbourneBranch" style="display:none">
    CONTENT
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
        div = $('#' + location);

        if($(this).val(location)) {
            div.show();
        } else {
            div.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vWLsU/)**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
        div = $('#' + location);

        $('div').hide();
            div.show();

    });
});​
```

**EDIT**

Currently the javascript will hide all the divs, we can prevent this if we assign some class to participating divs and replace $('div').hide(); statement with $('.somecssClass').hide();

```
<div id="sydneyBranch" class="somecssClass" style="display:none">
    CONTENT
</div>

<div id="melbourneBranch" class="somecssClass" style="display:none">
    CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: `$('div').hide()` will hide every div on page

Comment: Worked great, just had to add a class to the relevant DIV's so that the .hide() method only targeted them. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

add a common class to the content elements if you want them to be hidden again

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/q8G2N/

HTML:

```
   <div id="sydneyBranch" class="content" style="display:none">
```

JS:

```
$(function(){ /* shorthand $(document).ready(){*/

    $('#contact-location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val();
        /* don't do anything if blank option selected*/
         if( location !=''){
             $('.content').hide();
             $('#'+location).show();
         }

    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<select>
        <option data-div-id="div1">Option 1</option>
        <option data-div-id="div2">Option 2</option>
        <option data-div-id="div3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <div id="div1" class="container"  style="display:none">1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="container"  style="display:none">2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="container"  style="display:none">3</div>

    $(document).ready( function() { 
        $("select").change(function(){
            var divId = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-div-id");
            $(".container").hide();
            $("#" + divId).show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for:

```
var currentShowing = undefined;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
        div = $('#' + location);

        div.show();
        $(currentShowing).hide();
        currentShowing = div;

        if(currentShowing === undefined)
            div = currentShowing;
    });
});​
```